# how to query throught the nested relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i Have 3 Models 
Accommodation
accommodationRoom
roomPricingHistory
i am making a query through my hotel model for each user that select it picks the lowest price for each room and returns that after that i want to pick the room with the lowest price among all rooms  this is my query now:

```
           $data = Accommodation::with(['city','accommodationRoomsLimited.roomPricingHistorySearch' =>function($query) use($from_date,$to_date){
            $query->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $from_date);
            $query->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $to_date);
// here is where i want to pick the lowest price room and actually do a query on accommodationRoomsLimited based on roompricinghistorysearch result
                }])
                ->whereIn('city_id',$city_id)
                ->whereIn('grade_stars',$stars)
                ->orWhere('accommodation_type_id',$type_id)
                ->get();
```

here is the result output of my current query in api :

```
 {
    "id": 47,
    "operator_id": 12,
    "city_id": 139,
    "accommodation_status_id": 1,
    "child_age": null,
    "infant_age": null,
    "accommodation_provider_id": null,
    "grade_stars": 2,
    "accommodation_type_id": 1,
    "start_price": 1760000,
    "start_discount": 10,

    "english_name": null,
    "english_description": null,
    "english_address": null,
    "rules": null,
    "english_rules": null,
    "supply_team_note": null,
    "phone": null,
    "email": null,
    "cellphone": null,
    "receptionist": null,
    "is_removed": 0,
    "is_recommended": 0,
    "latitude": "32.66108300",
    "longitude": "51.6693880",
    "is_deleted": 0,
    "checkin_time": "14",
    "checkout_time": "12",
    "st_hid": 72,
    "created_at": "2019-05-22 19:20:02",
    "updated_at": "2019-05-25 17:59:06",
    "city": {
        "id": 139,

        "english_name": "Isfahan"
    },
    "accommodation_rooms_limited": [
        {
            "id": 4859,
            "accommodation_id": 47,
            "room_pricing_history_search": {
                "id": 15741,
                "accommodation_room_id": 4859,
                "net_price": null,
                "sales_price": 50,
                "extra_bed_price": null,
                "half_charge_price": null,
                "half_board_price": null,
                "full_board_price": null,
                "foreign_net_price": null,
                "foreign_sales_price": null,
                "foreign_extra_bed_price": null,
                "foreign_half_charge_price": null,
                "foreign_half_board_price": null,
                "foreign_full_board_price": null,
                "operator_id": 11,
                "commission_percent": null,
                "foreign_commission_percent": null,
                "discount_percent": 10,
                "foreign_discount_percent": null,
                "from_date": "2019-05-25 00:00:00",
                "to_date": "2019-08-30 23:59:59",
                "is_deleted": 0,
                "created_at": "2019-05-25 13:30:00",
                "updated_at": "2019-05-25 13:30:00"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 4860,
            "accommodation_id": 47,
            "room_pricing_history_search": {
                "id": 4990,
                "accommodation_room_id": 4860,
                "net_price": null,
                "sales_price": 1760000,
                "extra_bed_price": null,
                "half_charge_price": null,
                "half_board_price": null,
                "full_board_price": null,
                "foreign_net_price": null,
                "foreign_sales_price": null,
                "foreign_extra_bed_price": null,
                "foreign_half_charge_price": null,
                "foreign_half_board_price": null,
                "foreign_full_board_price": null,
                "operator_id": 11,
                "commission_percent": null,
                "foreign_commission_percent": null,
                "discount_percent": 10,
                "foreign_discount_percent": null,
                "from_date": "2019-05-25 00:00:00",
                "to_date": "2019-08-30 23:59:59",
                "is_deleted": 0,
                "created_at": "2019-05-25 13:30:00",
                "updated_at": "2019-05-25 13:30:00"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 4861,
            "accommodation_id": 47,
            "room_pricing_history_search": {
                "id": 4991,
                "accommodation_room_id": 4861,
                "net_price": null,
                "sales_price": 2270000,
                "extra_bed_price": null,
                "half_charge_price": null,
                "half_board_price": null,
                "full_board_price": null,
                "foreign_net_price": null,
                "foreign_sales_price": null,
                "foreign_extra_bed_price": null,
                "foreign_half_charge_price": null,
                "foreign_half_board_price": null,
                "foreign_full_board_price": null,
                "operator_id": 11,
                "commission_percent": null,
                "foreign_commission_percent": null,
                "discount_percent": 10,
                "foreign_discount_percent": null,
                "from_date": "2019-05-25 00:00:00",
                "to_date": "2019-08-30 23:59:59",
                "is_deleted": 0,
                "created_at": "2019-05-25 13:30:00",
                "updated_at": "2019-05-25 13:30:00"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 4862,
            "accommodation_id": 47,
            "room_pricing_history_search": {
                "id": 4992,
                "accommodation_room_id": 4862,
                "net_price": null,
                "sales_price": 2780000,
                "extra_bed_price": null,
                "half_charge_price": null,
                "half_board_price": null,
                "full_board_price": null,
                "foreign_net_price": null,
                "foreign_sales_price": null,
                "foreign_extra_bed_price": null,
                "foreign_half_charge_price": null,
                "foreign_half_board_price": null,
                "foreign_full_board_price": null,
                "operator_id": 11,
                "commission_percent": null,
                "foreign_commission_percent": null,
                "discount_percent": 10,
                "foreign_discount_percent": null,
                "from_date": "2019-05-25 00:00:00",
                "to_date": "2019-08-30 23:59:59",
                "is_deleted": 0,
                "created_at": "2019-05-25 13:30:00",
                "updated_at": "2019-05-25 13:30:00"
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

so on my accommodation_rooms_limited i want 1 room and 1 result to be cheapest room among all the rooms based on sales_price field of room_pricing_history_search .

Comment: What is it that you are asking?

Comment: @MichielLeegwater sorry i didnt understand

Comment: You provide a lot of details. But there is no question. So what is the problem?

Comment: i asked that really i think i want to pick lowest price room

Comment: An edit could improve the readability. I read over your issue and interpreted the lowest price you mentioned as something that was already realized. Therefore I could not spot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the query display at below

```
  <?php         

 $data = Accommodation::with(['city', 'accommodationRoomsLimited.roomPricingHistorySearch' => function($query) use($from_date,$to_date) {
      $query->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $from_date);
      $query->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $to_date);
      $query->OrderBy('sales_price' , 'ASC');
      $query->limit(1);    
    }])
    ->whereIn('city_id',$city_id)
    ->whereIn('grade_stars',$stars)
    ->orWhere('accommodation_type_id',$type_id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: i guess it would be sorting the roomPricingHistorySearch so when i write this query this relation return roomPricingHistorySearch null

Comment: i want to query the accommodationRoomsLimited relationship and take the lowest salesprice which is on roomPricingHistorySearch

Comment: There is no any sales_price in the accommodation_rooms_limited table.How could you do ?

Comment: yes thats the hard part that i want to get the lowest accommodation_rooms_limited based on room_pricing_history_search results